# $\langle\bar{a}, \mathbf{M}\bar{b}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{M}^T\bar{a},\bar{b}\rangle $ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to prove the statement in the title, where $\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{M}$ is a matrix, all of dimensions $n$ and $n\times n$ respectively, and $<\cdot,\cdot>$ denotes the standard inner product.

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL9N2.png)

I keep getting that it should not be transposed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: You are not calculating the matrix multiplication correctly. It should be like this: $[\mathbf{M}x]_{i} = \sum_{j} M_{ij} x_j$

Comment: Ahh I just realized, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ah I figured it out, here is my proof/derivation in case anyone stumbles across this in the future with the same question.

[Derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drZnx.png)